# How to configure VS 'toolbox' mac 7.4.3 version

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-mac, visual-studio-monaco

I am attempting to use newly installed; Visual Studio 7.4.3 on mac for simple asp.net / C# web forms. (I do not have a windows machine). I need to configure a data source via the Data Source wizard that is typically available via the 'toolbox' bar after dragging an item to the file or editor.

The toolbox is completely empty, I'm concluding I must configure the toolbox manually to populate it - but have research and found 0 solutions on how to do this. There are a handful of similar issues reported for mac 2017 version on the visual studio website but none seemed to be solved..

Through instructions, ultimately I am trying to achieve this to setup a data source for form elements.

> Select the Configure Data Source command from the smart tag menu of
>   the SQL data source for the data list control to start the Configure
>   Data Source wizard.

There is no accessible configure data source command, nor smart tag menu - I read on the docs this is typically accessible after dragging an element from the 'toolbox' which I can't do because it's empty.

Any insight on how to achieve this with Mac Visual Studio 7.4.3?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no toolbox or design view option available for Visual Studio in Mac. So what you can do is to manually add code to your .aspx file as below:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="CustomerId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        CustomerId:
        <asp:Label ID="CustomerIdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CustomerId") %>' />
        <br />
        CustomerName:
        <asp:Label ID="CustomerNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CustomerName") %>' />
        <br />
        <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Customers]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```